# Save data from modal form using AJAX

Tags: php, ajax

I would like to be able to save the data I entered on a modal form to a file and return the data into an alert after submission.

This is the current AJAX I have.

```
$("#submit").click(function(){

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "save.php",
            data: $('#form1').serialize(),
            success: function(r){
                 alert (r);
            return false;
            },
            dataType: "html"
        });

        $('.modal').modal('show');
    });
```

If you need to see save.php, here it is:

```
<?php
    // check if a form was submitted
    if( !empty( $_POST ) ){
        // convert form data to json format
        $data = array(
          "name" => $_POST['name1'],
          "branch_address" => $_POST['bAddress1'],
          "officer_in_charge" => $_POST['officer1'],
          "contact_number" => $_POST['contactN1']
        ); //processes the fields on the form

        $json = json_encode( $data );
        $file = 'entries.json';
        // write to file
        file_put_contents( $file, $json, FILE_APPEND);
?>
```

Comment: add preventDeault() to prevent default submission.

Comment: In the alert, you'd like to see name, branch address, etc.. right?

Comment: @larsAnders yes and also save them to a file named entries.json which is on save.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to echo the json data from the PHP file, like this:

```
   $json = json_encode( $data );
   $file = 'entries.json';
   // write to file
   file_put_contents( $file, $json, FILE_APPEND);
   echo $json;
```

This is how data is returned via ajax - you simply echo it out, then it should be captured by the script as the variable `r` in this case.

Comment: Is there no need to put anything in "data: {}" like the values from the modal form?

Comment: No, you're echoing out the data in JSON format, which is already understood by the javascript that will receive it.

Answer (score 1):

File save.php

```
<?php
    // check if a form was submitted
    if( !empty( $_POST ) ){
        // convert form data to json format
        $data = array(
          "name" => $_POST['name1'],
          "branch_address" => $_POST['bAddress1'],
          "officer_in_charge" => $_POST['officer1'],
          "contact_number" => $_POST['contactN1']
        ); //processes the fields on the form

        $json = json_encode( $data );
        $file = 'entries.json';
        // write to file
        file_put_contents( $file, $json, FILE_APPEND);
        echo $json;  
?>
```

Comment: Is there no need to put anything in "data: {}" like the values from the modal form?

Answer (score 0):

Use `echo $json;` after the line  `file_put_contents( $file, $json, FILE_APPEND);`